# Asking to enter a parameter value that already exists

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a three column table of price breaks called "FPB" that looks like this:

```
[Part Number] [Quantity] [Price]
 AAA-AAAA　　　　　100　　　1.23
 AAA-AAAA　　　　　200　　　1.15
 BBB-BBBB　　　　　100　　　5.60
 CCC-CCCC　 　　　 500　　　3.21
 ....
```

Where each part number has multiple entries in multiple rows.

I'm trying to reorganize the table to look more like this

```
[Part Number] [Quantity1] [Price 1] [Quantity 2] [Price 2] [Quantity 3....
AAA-AAAA　　　　　　100　　　1.23　　  　200　    　　1.15　　　....
BBB-BBBB　　　　　　100　　　5.60　 　　 ...
CCC-CCCC　　 　　　 500　　　3.21　　　  ...
...
```

Where each part number has all its entries combined into one row. The first quantity column should have the lowest available quantity, the second should have the second smallest etc. I am trying to do this by first creating a 1-column table with just the unique part numbers using GROUP BY, and then creating more tables for each column that has the information I want in that column, and then joining it by Part Number. The problem comes when calculating the second smallest quantity for each type, done in the second to last section.

```
SELECT PNs.[Part Number], Q1T.Q1, P1T.Price, Q2T.Q2
FROM
(SELECT
[Part Number]
FROM FPB
GROUP BY [Part Number]
) AS PNs,

(SELECT
[Part Number],
MIN(Quantity) AS Q1
FROM FPB
GROUP BY [Part Number]
) AS Q1T,

(SELECT
*
FROM FPB
) AS P1T,

(SELECT
[Part Number],
MIN(IIF(Quantity>Q1T.Q1,Quantity)) AS Q2
FROM FPB
GROUP BY [Part Number]
) AS Q2T

WHERE
PNs.[Part Number] = Q1T.[Part Number]
AND P1T.[Part Number] = PNs.[Part Number]
AND P1T.Quantity = Q1T.Q1
AND Q2T.[Part Number] = PNs.[Part Number]
```

When I run this query, it asks me to enter a parameter value for Q1T.Q1, even though it already exists. If I remove the code section for Q2T, as well as any references to Q2, it will work without a problem, and it won't ask about a value for the other instances of Q1T.Q1. Why doesn't Q1T.Q1 have a value just for that section, and how can I fix it? As a side note, I'm using the SQL features of a program called PHPRunner, and its client doesn't support UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT/CREATE queries, UNION, and DISTINCT.

Comment: I know this is a dup, just can't find the question at the moment.

Comment: You are looking for `PIVOT` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY)` but you need include your rdbms so we can provide you the right sample. Or you can google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this.

```
select
    p1.PartNumber,
    ifnull(max(p2.Quantity), 0) + 1 as LowerQuantity,
    p1.Quantity as UpperQuantity,
    p1.Price,
    count(p2.PartNumber) + 1 as PriceTier
from
    FPB p1 left outer join FPB p2
        on p2.PartNumber = p1.PartNumber and p2.Quantity < p1.Quantity
```

From there it's easy to pivot in order to insert into a new table:

```
into into NewFPB (PartNumber, Quantity1, Price1, Quantity2, Price2, ...)
select
    PartNumber,
    min(switch(PriceTier = 1, UpperQuantity)) as Quantity1,
    min(switch(PriceTier = 2, UpperQuantity)) as Quantity2, ...
    min(switch(PriceTier = 1, Price)) as Price1,
    min(switch(PriceTier = 2, Price)) as Price2, ...        
from (
    select
        p1.PartNumber,
        ifnull(max(p2.Quantity), 0) + 1 as LowerQuantity,
        p1.Quantity as UpperQuantity,
        p1.Price,
        count(p2.PartNumber) + 1 as PriceTier
    from
        FPB p1 left outer join FPB p2
            on p2.PartNumber = p1.PartNumber and p2.Quantity < p1.Quantity
) data
```

You might have to tweak it a little bit for Access to accept it. But the core ideas are there.

Comment: I see, so I can only manipulate named tables in a "higher" SELECT statement, not in "parallel" ones. I was able to work out a solution with this idea, thank you :)

Comment: Without common table expressions or cross apply you're basically right. Access/Jet SQL is limited and I believe even this form of the query would have been invalid only a few versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

The query you call is incorrect.

Q1T is inner select statement , and in Q2T (other inner select statement) , you can't use any field from Q1T

The SQL Server  raise error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

To overcome this limitation , you should use **Common Table Expressions CTE**
for PNs, Q1T, P1T, Q2T

CTE is like dynamic view.
It's a new feature since sql 2008 and It's a very powerful.

review: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Try to Draw a relational data model for these four CTE to be sure that a relation exist between them based on your where conditions.
I think the logic in this query may raise runtime error during execution:

e.g. The multi-part identifier "Q1T.Q1" could not be bound.

**Edit:**

For **Ms-Access** you can create four queries for: PNs, Q1T, P1T, Q2T every one is in a separate query, and the fifth query join these queries and add where conditions.
In this case you will not get any syntax error. and will get **Data model** with relation  free :) .

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it seems like CTE's are a bit too new for PHPRunner, and MS Access, where I'm storing the tables, doesn't seem to support it either. Is there an equivalent function in MS Access?

Comment: Welcome. In fact i see your tags is sql-server and tsql .Kindly Tag your question Ms-access and remove tsql,sql-server.

Comment: I did not add those tags, I only tagged sql. I'm not sure how those got there. But I will remove them and add the Access tag. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, by the time you define the derived table Q2T, Q1T is still an invalid object. You need to try to work around this issue.

**EDIT**:
Suppose you only got 2-level columns to handle, the code is listed below, i tested it. It works well.

```
select q5.*,q3.quantity, q3.price

from

(select *
from FPB as Q1
where 0 = (select count(distinct(quantity)) from FPB as Q2 where Q2.quantity < Q1.quantity AND Q2.[part number] = Q1.[part number])) as Q5
,
(
select distinct(temp.[part number]),Q2.quantity, Q2.price from FPB as temp
left join
(select *
from FPB as Q4
where 1 = (select count(distinct(quantity)) from #test as Q2 where Q2.quantity < Q4.quantity AND Q2.[PART NUMBER] = Q4.[PART NUMBER])) as Q2
on temp.[PART NUMBER] = Q2.[PART NUMBER]
) as Q3

where Q5.[PART NUMBER] = Q3.[PART NUMBER]
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. They're on the same 'processing level' so to speak. I'll see what kind of work-arounds I can find.